# My WP app has external dependencies not under my control, how do I fix issues w/o resubmitting to the marketplace?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, xpath, windows-phone

I have a bunch of external dependencies in my app (XML, HTML, Web Services etc).

These can change w/o notice. How do I allow myself to fix them without having all traffic go through my server and without waiting for an app to be certified by the marketplace?

[]

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a legimate question.

Comment: I read the FAQ and it said that this type of "self question/answer"  is encouraged. So must be the contents. :)

Comment: Accidentally pressed the wrong button on the phone, sorry! Please make a small edit so I can change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a series of blog posts about exactly how to do this by using XPath and Javascript to be able to customize your app and allowing you to fix/change elements in your application without going through recertification.

You can take a look at the first post in the series and take it from there.

http://socialeboladev.wordpress.com/2012/09/03/change-resilient-windows-phone-apps-2/

Answer (score 2):

You could post your app at SiteApps.com. By the way, they hold your files in their CDN and only updates if you programatically updates.